# SQL - Distinct count then group by several columns

Tags: sql

I have two tables, and I'd like to leverage the following columns:

UsersTable

[image]

OrgTable

[image]

I am using a query that can brings me distinct count of users either by Status or by OrgName:

E.g. by OrgName

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT E.Person) AS #Users
        , F.OrgName
  FROM UsersTable E left join OrgTable F 
  on E.OrgID=F.OrgID 
   where F.OrgName in ( 'A', 'B', 'C') and E.Status in ('Active', 'Contingent staff', 'Terminated')
   group by F.OrgName
```

[image]

But how can I get the # Users by both columns? Such as

[image]

Thanks!

Nothing I tried yielded the expected result, which is

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your simple data and the expected output as text not images ? Also can you tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: The table aliases E for UsersTable, and F for OrgTable don't make much sense. I'd consider U and O instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying @SelVazi. I am not able to paste the data as text, the only option I had was to allow it to be images.

Comment: @jarlh, in my actual database, the tables are dimEmployee (E) and dimFunctionHierarchy (F), hence E and F. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another column to your Select and Group By.

---

```
select o.orgname, u.status, count(u.person) as users
from users u
join org o
  on u.orgid = o.orgid
where o.orgname in ('Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C')
  and u.status in ('Active', 'Contingent Staff', 'Terminated')
group by o.orgname, u.status
order by 1;
```

| orgname | status | users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Active | 2 |
| Company A | Terminated | 1 |
| Company B | Contingent Staff | 2 |
| Company C | Active | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ZZuRrJn65Ax3tupEyPSQs/0)

Comment: Thanks, @Isolated, this was simple enough and gets me what I need!
Best regards!

Comment: If this answers your question, then please consider marking the Accept flag to let others know this has been resolved.